# Exporting map, new layers show up

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layers, export

I am using ArcMap 10.6.1 and I am trying to export a map as a TIFF file. When I'm in layoutview the map looks ok, but when I export it, new layers show up. Or the scale of the layers change or something.

[image: What the map looks like in layout view]

[image: What the exported map looks like. Had to do a screenshot, since the original file was too large to upload here]

As you can see in the screenshot there are 7 citynames in the map. When I export it the layers change. It seems as the map scale is changing when I export it. I've checked the maximum and minimum scale of the layer and it is not what's causing the problem. I'm quite new to ArcMap, but this wasn't a problem a while ago.When I try to export old maps that worked fine before,I get the same problem. Could it be a function I've checked or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing I'll check is the paper size you are printing to.

From your images, image one seems to me a map document set to display the map on a digital 20X20cm squared-shape size paper (I can see that on the ruler grid).

In the second image it seems the page is larger, being (e.g.) the labels showing up smaller than they were in your document (their font is probably the same).

Go in File -> Page and Print setup and ensure the page size is the same as the one you want to print/export to.

For example, if you want to export to a A2 paper size, do something like this (notice that I checked the last box to ensure that my map elements would scale proportionally to the changed paper size):

[image]

[image]

Of course, if you don't want to print to a squared paper (which is unlikely), if I were you I would change the paper size in ArcMap to match that of the printer and adjust the size of the map box within the layout to a square area.